# WebView blank; EGL_BAD_DISPLAY errors

Tags: java, android, user-interface, webview

I'm trying to load a webview in a new activity for my application. When I run the app the webview is a blank white screen. I've looked at other posts and haven't found an answer that works. These are the two errors I'm getting:

E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)                                                                                                                                                                  [ 02-28 22:23:26.838 30796:30836 D/         ]                                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x865fc280, tid 30836

E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver

```
public class VideoPlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebview;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //initialize setup
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplayactivity);

    intent = getIntent();
    mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    //view.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mywebview.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("url"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the SSL error, you should ignore SSL certificate error.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
       public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
           handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
       }
   });
```